# Cannot separate columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having an issue with calculated columns.

When I select a date in the slicer, i want two columns to show in my matrix: the selected date and the same period last year. I have calculated columns to do this, but when I select them, this is what happens:

[image: see picture]

Instead of having 2 columns, one stays above the other. Does anyone know why this happens? How can I change it?

Thank you so much in advance.

Sílvia

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the "Matrix" Visualization, you have "abr2015" and "abr2014" in the Columns Section. Move them to the Values section and you should get what you are looking for.